# Adding readline to sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, expect, readline

I tried to create a script that would add readline abilities to the sqlite3 commands like a history and moving your cursor. I came up with this so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pty'
require 'expect'
require 'readline'

PTY.spawn("sqlite3") do |reader, writer, pid|
    reader.expect("sqlite> ")
    writer.puts(Readline.readline("sqlite> ", true))
end
```

But I have no idea how to get it to print the output of the command they entered. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: You should read about [`rlwrap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) -- it might simplify your life.

Comment: OMG thank you! I will definitely use this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a play with this after finding [this tutorial](http://www.42klines.com/2010/08/14/what-to-expect-from-the-ruby-expect-library.html).

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'
require 'readline'


PTY.spawn("sqlite3") do |reader, writer, pid|
   cmd = Readline.readline("prompt> ", true);
   reader.expect(/^sqlite\>/) {  |r| writer.printf("%s\n",cmd) }
   puts reader.expect(/^sqlite\>/)[0]
end
```

So in a nutshell, for your example, all you need to add is this:

```
 puts reader.expect("sqlite> ")[0]
```

Playing with this a bit more I added a little loop that asks for commands, sends them to sqllite3 and sends back the result:

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'
require 'readline'


PTY.spawn("sqlite3") do |reader, writer, pid|
   reader.expect(/^sqlite\>/)                   # Read up till the prompt.
   loop {
      cmd = Readline.readline("prompt> ", true);   # Get a command.
      writer.printf("%s\n",cmd)                    # Send it.

      r = reader.expect(/^sqlite\>/)               # Get the result
      r[0].lines.to_a[0..-2].each do |l|           # Turn into an array without last line.
         unless l.match(/^ /)                      # Ignore the indented lines
            puts l                                 # Show the result to user
         end
      end
   end
```

The `r[0].lines.to_a[0..-2].join` is just some black magic to remove the last line.

Comment: Do you know how I can get it to just give the output of the command after entering it, like this: `Hello World` instead of this: `select "Hello World"; Hello World`

Comment: Updated answer to only return the query result.

Comment: where is the curly brace closed?